# imaplib モジュールで未読メールを指定件数のみ読み込みたい

Tags: python, python3, gmail

#### やりたいこと

gmailに複数の未読メールがあっても一つだけを読み込みたいです。
現在は下記のコードだと全ての未読メールが読み込まれます。
一つだけを読み込みするため、どのように指定すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
import imaplib, re, email, six, dateutil.parser

mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('example.gmail.com',993)     #SMTPは993,POPは995
mail.login('example@jp','exam123')
mail.select('example.jp')   #メールボックスの選択

#UNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
type,data=mail.search(None,'UNSEEN') #メールボックス内にあるすべてのデータを取得ALL

for i in data[0].split():   #data分繰り返す
 ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')    #メールの情報を取得
 ms=email.message_from_string(x[0][1].decode('iso-2022-jp'))    #パースして取得

 #差出人を取得
 ad=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('From'))
 ms_code=ad[0][1]
 if(ms_code!=None):
  address=ad[0][0].decode(ms_code)
  address+=ad[1][0].decode(ms_code)
 else:
  address=ad[0][0]
 
 #タイトルを取得
 sb=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('Subject'))
 ms_code=sb[0][1]
 if(ms_code!=None):
  sbject=sb[0][0].decode(ms_code)
 else:
  ms_code=sb[1][1]
  sbject=sb[1][0].decode(ms_code)
 
 #本文を取得
 maintext=ms.get_payload()

 mail.store(i,'+FLAGS', '\\Seen')

 #メールの日時を取得
 time = dateutil.parser.parse(ms.get('Date')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")[:-1]
 print(time)

 #出力
 print(sbject)
 print(address)
 print(maintext)
 
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

Comment: 単純にfor文の末尾で`break`するか、for文を使わず`ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')`を`ok,x=mail.fetch(data[0].split()[0], '(RFC822)')`に書き換えることで対応可能でしょうか。cf:本家SOの[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66401210)

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法でできました！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

単純にfor文の末尾で`break`する方法で対応可能です。

またはfor文を使わずに`ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')`を
`ok,x=mail.fetch(data[0].split()[0], 'RFC822')`に書き換える方法もあります。

本家SOの類似質問
[Python imaplib: get the first unread email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66401210)

※[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77576/imaplib-%e3%83%a2%e3%82%b8%e3%83%a5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%81%a7%e6%9c%aa%e8%aa%ad%e3%83%a1%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e6%8c%87%e5%ae%9a%e4%bb%b6%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bf%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment87676_77576)を回答化しました。