# try ブロックでエラーが発生しても、意図した通り except に飛ばない

Tags: python, python3, exception

##### やりたいこと

Pythonでメール内の処理でエラーが発生したら、特定のサイトにエラー通知を飛ばしたいです。
下記のコードのようにtryのブロック内にエラー通知を検知したいです。

- if でメールが無い場合: 正常終了
- エラーがある場合: exceptに飛ばしたい

メールの有無を判定する分岐

```
if not time:　
　return d["NULL"]
else:
   print('DL OK　メールがあるので処理続く')
```

現状だとtryのブロック内でエラーが発生してもexceptに飛ばないです。
定義した関数で return を利用しているからでしょうか。

```
import imaplib, re, email, six, dateutil.parser
import json
import requests

def a(d): 
 try:
  mail=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)  #SMTPは993,POPは995
  mail.login('example@co.jp','12345')
  mail.select('testlabel')  #メールボックスの選択
 
  #UNSEEN未読メールを読み込む
  type,data=mail.search(None,'UNSEEN') #メールボックス内にあるすべてのデータを取得ALL
 
  for i in data[0].split():   #data分繰り返す
   ok,x=mail.fetch(i,'RFC822')    #メールの情報を取得
   ms=email.message_from_string(x[0][1].decode('iso-2022-jp'))    #パースして取得
 
  #差出人を取得
  ad=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('From'))
  ms_code=ad[0][1]
  if(ms_code!=None):
   address=ad[0][0].decode(ms_code)
   address+=ad[1][0].decode(ms_code)
  else:
   address=ad[0][0]
 
  #タイトルを取得
  sb=email.header.decode_header(ms.get('Subject'))
  ms_code=sb[0][1]
  if(ms_code!=None):
   sbject=sb[0][0].decode(ms_code)
  else:
   ms_code=sb[1][1]
   sbject=sb[1][0].decode(ms_code)
 
  #本文を取得
  maintext=ms.get_payload()
 
  #メールの日時を取得
  time = dateutil.parser.parse(ms.get('Date')).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")[:-1]
  print(time)
 
  #出力
  print(sbject)
  print(address)
  print(maintext)
 
 
 #Data confirm null確認
  if not time:
   return d["NULL"]
   #print('NULL')
  else:
   print('DL OK　メールがあるので処理続く')
 
  mail.close()
  mail.logout() 
 
 except :
      # エラー発生時ここにくる
      example_url ="https://wh.example.com/connect-api/webhook/12234/abcd"
      example_header ={   
         
      "Accept": "application/vnd.tosslab.example-v2+json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
      example_payload ={
         
      "body": "Error",
      "connectColor": "#FF0000",
      "connectInfo": [{
         
      "title":"正常に実行できませんでしたので、\nご確認お願い致します。"
      }
      ]
      }
      # post to example
      requests.post(url=example_url, data=json.dumps(example_payload), headers=example_header, timeout=10)
 
 print('正常終了')
```

Comment: インデントがずれておかしな動作になっていませんか？あるいは質問時の転記ミス？ 以前の記事 [imaplib モジュールで未読メールを指定件数のみ読み込みたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77576/26370) と照らし合わせて確認してみてください。あとはtry-exceptとは関係無いですがこんな記事が参考になるかも。[imaplibで受信したメールを取得する](https://myafu-python.com/smtplib-imaplib/#toc3)

Comment: こちら回答ありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

さらに良いことに、あなたは例外を投げることができます

```py
  #...
  if not time:
   raise ValueError("Value null")
   #return d["NULL"]
   #print('NULL')
  else:
    #...
```

これにより、このブロックは `except` ブロックに渡されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法で試してみます。